# Temp folder becoming administrator only?

Tags: windows, permissions

`%tmp%` is used by almost all programs, Windows 8 is buggy as hell from release to the latest update, and one fine day all programs started behaving weird, and one was giving an access denied message for the temp folder.

I noticed that the temp folder has only two access groups: Administrator (with full permissions), and Everyone(with read only access). I added the group "Users", gave it full permission and thought the problem was fixed.

But this keeps coming back every week or so, the permissions are getting reset on its own, and the User group is getting removed automatically. Is there a permanent solution?

Comment: which application is giving you trouble ?

Comment: The issue isn't about any specific application, it's about temp folder